# Gradle DSL method not found : android()

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, lint

While running lint on terminal, I added -

```
android {  
    lintOptions {  
    abortOnError false  
}
```

to supress lint error. But, while building or syncing gradle, it gives me following error - Gradle DSL method not found : android(). How do I resolve it?

build.gradle (Project):

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
   buildscript {
      repositories {
      jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
  }
  android {  
         lintOptions {  
            abortOnError false  
         }
     }

allprojects {
     repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
 }
```

Comment: Can you post your gradle file?

Comment: Make sure gradle plugin is to apply plugin: 'com.android.application' in build.gradle file. Also your Gradle build path is set application level build.gradle file like classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

Comment: @user2163887, add it as an answer.